# Populating a New Array from Corresponding Index of Elements from 3 Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have been trying to resolve an issue where my conditional logic doesn't work when I have the same string value in two elements of an array. I have been trying it with for-loops, but without success.

What occurs to me after thinking about it is that the best way to handle this is to take my three arrays - of which, in my use case, there will ALWAYS be an equal number of elements, and mash them together into a new array of objects -- taking the corresponding value from each array element to popular the new array of objects.

Imagine data like this:

```
const goalScorers = ['John Smith', 'Dave Jones', 'Rob Porter'];
const goalTimes = [4, 23, 56];
const goalTypes = ['penalty', 'breakaway', 'header'];
```

How best should I handle this to end up with array like this:

```
const combinedArr = [
  { scorer: 'John Smith', time: 4, type: 'penalty' },
  { scorer: 'Dave Jones', time: 23, type: 'breakaway' },
  { scorer: 'Rob Porter', time: 56, type: 'header' }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map over one of the arrays. The callback function receives the array index, it can use that to access the corresponding elements of the other arrays.

```
const combinedArr = goalScorers.map((scorer, i) => ({
    scorer: scorer, time: goalTimes[i], type: goalTypes[i]
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

If all the arrays are sorted correctly, so each index is the same instance in every array than you can parse one with `map` and use index to populate other fields

```js
const goalScorers = ['John Smith', 'Dave Jones', 'Rob Porter'];
const goalTimes = [4, 23, 56];
const goalTypes = ['penalty', 'breakaway', 'header'];

const newArray = goalScorers.map((element, index) => {
  return {
    scorer: element,
    time: goalTimes[index],
    type: goalTypes[index],
  }
})

console.log(newArray)
```